# Conditional overloaded method call based on parameter value typescript compilation error TS2322 TS2554

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function that take another function as a parameter. The parameter has different signature based on another parameter.

I declare the function like this :

```
function edit({
    load, 
    onEdit
} : {
        load : true, 
        // options is way more complex in real life
        onEdit : (options : {a : number}) => void  
    } | {
        load : false, 
        onEdit : () => boolean 
    })
{ /* */ }
```

and would like to call it like this :

```
edit({
    load:true, 
    onEdit : ({a}) => {
        console.log('do something fun with a', a);
    }
}); 

// OR

edit({
    load:false, 
    onEdit : () => {
        return false; 
    }
})
```

I try to implement the method like this :

```
function edit({
    load, onEdit
} : {
        load : true, 
        // options is way more complex in real life
        onEdit : (options : {a : number}) => void  
    } | {
        load : false, 
        onEdit : () => boolean 
    })
{
    let result : boolean; 
    if(load){
        const o = { a : 1 }; 
        onEdit(o); 
        result = true; 
    } else {
        // error TS2322: Type 'boolean | void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
        //  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
        // error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. 
        result = onEdit(); 
    }
    console.log('result', result);
}
```

but I get this error

> error TS2322: Type 'boolean | void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. 
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

and

> error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

I try adding a Type guard

```
    const shouldLoad = (fn: typeof onEdit): fn is (options: { a: number }) => void => {
        return load;
    };
```

but id didn't help

How can i implement the edit method with type safety ?

Comment: [Works for me](https://tsplay.dev/wQV0jN), can you edit that playground link so it's a [mre] of the problem you're having? I just copy-and-pasted your implementation at the end of the question followed by the calls in the question, and added two `console.log`s so we could see which branch was taken. Seems to be good.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the playground link. It works with 4.6.2 but not for 4.5.5. It looks a bug has been fixed with 4.6.2. I will try to update my react app to use TS 4.6.2. I try to find the related issue on github but cound find it. Any idea how I can make it work with 4.5.5 ?

Comment: Ah, I [see what you mean](https://tsplay.dev/Ndo8Mw), well-diagnosed! If you know it'll work correctly in a slightly later version, that seems like a reasonable time for a `@ts-ignore` with a comment saying to remove it when you upgrade. :-) Or you could do `result = (onEdit as () => boolean)();` (again with a note).

Comment: I migrated to the latest typescript version and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typescript code is valid for typescript v4.6.2 but produces error for v4.5.5.

There is 3 solutions for this problem :

1. Migrate to typescript v4.6.2+
2. add a @ts-ignore with a comment

   ```
    let result : boolean; 
    if(load) {
        const o = { a : 1 }; 
        onEdit(o); 
        result = true; 
    } else {
        // @ts-ignore - typescript issue with 4.5.5 
        result = onEdit(); 
    }
   ```
3. force the conversion

   ```
    let result : boolean; 
    if(load) {
        const o = { a : 1 }; 
        onEdit(o); 
        result = true; 
    } else {
        // cast is required for typescript 4.5.5 
        result = (onEdit as () => boolean)(); 
    }
   ```